# How to draw straight line in Blender

Tags: draw-mode

I am very new to Blender and I'm wondering how to draw a straight line in it, as depicted in the picture.

[image]

Comment: hello, are your talking about the Sculpt mode?

Comment: I am currently in object mode and am unsure whether I need to switch to another mode

Answer (score 0):

Switch to *Sculpt* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>), keep the default brush, in the *Stroke* panel choose *Stroke Method > Line, Spacing > 1%*:

[image]

in the *Falloff* panel choose *Custom* and create this kind of falloff profile:

[image]

Sculpt on the surface of your object:

[image]